# How to convert Decimal to GIS coordinates in SQL?

Tags: azure-synapse

I have GIS coordinates stored in one of our systems as Decimals. However, I would like to display them as Degrees:mins:secs. I tried Googling but couldn't find anything for SQL. Could someone please help me?

```
    CREATE TABLE gis 
  ( 
     latitude DECIMAL(13, 10) 
  ); 

INSERT INTO gis 
SELECT -95.8833333000 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 32.5530555550 
UNION ALL 
SELECT -163.3000000000
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this based on [this blog](http://www.chilledsql.com/welcome/tip_category_dataconversion/tip_category_convertgpsdecimaltodmsstring). Hope this helps someone in future.

```
SELECT [Latitude] AS [Latitude], 
       CAST([Latitude] AS INT) AS [Degrees], 
       REPLACE(CAST(([Latitude] - CAST([Latitude] AS INT)) * 60 AS INT), '-', '') AS [Minutes], 
       REPLACE(CAST((3600 * ([Latitude] - CAST([Latitude] AS INT))) - (CAST(([Latitude] - CAST([Latitude] AS INT)) * 60 AS INT) * 60) AS INT), '-', '') AS [Seconds]
FROM gis
```